# How to pass an array to a function so that the original array's value doesn't change when changing the array's values in that function?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

```
using namespace std;
#include<iostream>
int passarr(int b[],int s)
{
   //Some Modification in the array b
    b[0]=0;
    b[s-1]=0;

    //Printing the array b
    for(int i=0;i<s;i++)
    {
        cout<<b[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
int main()
{
    int arr[100];
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>arr[i];
    }

    //Function call and passing array a to the function`
    passarr(arr,n);

    //Printing the array arr
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }
}
```

In this code, I have passed array `arr` to function `passarr()` which performs some modifications. The problem is that modifications reflect on the original array too. Is there any way to pass the array to a function so that the original array does not get changed while performing any operation in the function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any way to pass the array to a function so that the original array does not get changed while performing any operation in the function?

Choices that I can think of:

1. Make a copy of the array in the function and modify the copy. Leave the input array untouched.
2. Pass a `std::vector` by value. Any changes to the argument won't affect the object in the calling function.
3. If you know the size of the array at compile time, pass a `std::array` by value.  Any changes to the argument won't affect the object in the calling function.

Comment: i have a timing constraint, so that's why making a copy of the original array won't work.

Comment: You can modify a copy, modify the original, or not modify at all. I don't see any other choices.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by the answer of [R Sahu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51101539/8344060), if you do not want to make a copy, there is not much you can do within the constraint of the Standard.

However, you could keep track of your changes in a different data-structure. A possibility would be [`std:map<class key, class value>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/):

- The key of the map would be the array index of type `int`
- The value is the modified value of your original array.

From this point forward you only need to do a conditional check if the array index is in the map. This could be done using ['std::map::find'](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/). Thus :

- If the array index is in the `std::map`, return the value in `std::map`
- If the array index isn't in the `std::map`, return the original array value

If you do a sequential array traversal, this can be sped up by using the property of the map traversal. In the presented example, this could be :

```
 int passarr(int b[],int s) {
    std::map<int,int> mod;
    std::map<int,int>::iterator it;

    //Some Modification in the array b
    mod[0]=0;
    mod[s-1]=0;

    //Printing the array b
    it=mod.begin();
    for(int i=0;i<s;i++) {
        if (i == it->first) {
           std::cout << it->second << " ";
           it++;
        else { std::cout<<b[i]<<" "; }
    }
    std::cout<<endl;
}
```